# Can you define a server's locations in multiple nginx config files?

Tags: nginx

I have multiple ruby apps running on the on the same host:

```
~/app1
~/app2
~/app3
```

And I want to have nginx proxy these apps using sub-directories like:

```
   http://example.com/app1
   http://example.com/app2
   http://example.com/app3
```

I'm curious if nginx supports me being able define these locations in multiple files, so that I could keep each configuration with the app, instead of having one monolithic config file for all of the apps:

```
~/app1/nginx.conf
~/app2/nginx.conf
~/app3/nginx.conf
```

My naive attempt of defining the server with a single location directive in each of the 3 config files led to `conflicting server name "example.com" on [::]:80, ignored` with a configs that look like this:

```
upstream app1 { server 127.0.0.1:4567; }
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  servername  example.com
  location    /app1 {
     proxy_pass  http://app1;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to organize the configs this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include external configs via include:

```
include /path/to/config1.conf;
include /path/to/config2.conf;
include /path/to/confdir/*.conf;

server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen      [::]:80;
    listen      80;
}
```

And inside separate config you can use any valid code blocks:

```
upstream app1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://app1;
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  Doesn't the upstream module need to be outside the server module block?

Comment: Looks like location directive is not allowed outside the server block. At least for me, nginx reports `"location" directive is not allowed here`.

Comment: Yeah...I don't see a simple way of doing that properly without multiple files per application: one that would work inside a server block, one that would work outside. I guess for flexibility and to make it clean a wildcard could be used: `include /etc/nginx/above_server.d/*` and `include /etc/nginx/in_server.d/*`

Comment: This answer is wrong

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer given it doesn't work?

Answer (score 18):

I believe, you could use this configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen      [::]:80;
    listen      80;

    include /path/to/applications/*/nginx.conf;
}
```

and then in each application's directory configure the redirection like this:

```
location    /app1 {
    proxy_pass  http://app1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
}
```

Comment: The downside would be that you can't define multiple upstreams within the `server` block but I think the OP's use case is well served by this answer.