# Use "include" in nginx server block but where to save?

Tags: nginx

All of the examples I have seen, used "include something.conf" in the http block.

Is it possible to use "include something.conf" in the server block? If yes, where is the best practice to save the conf?

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    include (where)/somethingcool.conf

}
```

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/618889/can-you-define-a-servers-locations-in-multiple-nginx-config-files

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can put the file wherever you want, it's up to you.

If you use a *relative* path, however, then it will be relative to the nginx configuration directory (e.g. `/etc/nginx` on Linux, `/usr/local/etc/nginx` on BSD, etc.).

I personally create a directory `/etc/nginx/includes` and place these configuration bits in there. For example:

```
server {
    server_name deploy.example.com;

    include includes/listen-80;
    include includes/letsencrypt;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Where `/etc/nginx/includes/listen-80` contains:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```

And `/etc/nginx/includes/letsencrypt` contains:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Of course I have many other such configuration bits.

Answer (score 1):

@michaelhampton answered the question that, at first read, I thought you had asked, too.  As his example shows, you can use the [`include` directive in a `server` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include).  You can actually use it in any block, so using it in the server block is fine, too.